# Converting C# to VB.net is not working

Tags: vb.net

I have translated some code from C# to VB.net for the purpose of getting Folder Browser functionality. The link to the code is here.....

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/DirectoryBrowsing.aspx

My issue is that I have not been able to correcly translate these two lines of code to VB.net.

```
TreeView1.TreeNodeExpanded +=new TreeNodeEventHandler(TreeView1_TreeNodeExpanded);
TreeView1.SelectedNodeChanged += new EventHandler(TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged);
```

Every translator I have used has simply dropped the semicolon from the end of each line. But the editor still does not like them.

I could some help with this as it seems this effects the refresh of the selected folder in the tree view control.

[image]

I don't get to see the C drive folder unless I type the path in the text box, and the folder will still not expand.

thank you,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this:

```
AddHandler TreeView1.TreeNodeExpanded, AddressOf TreeView1_TreeNodeExpanded
AddHandler TreeView1.SelectedNodeChanged, AddressOf TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged
```

**Edit:**
A different way to do this would be to apply it at the method level:

```
Protected Sub TreeView1_TreeNodeExpanded(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as TreeNodeEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.TreeNodeExpanded

    ' Some code

End Sub

Protected Sub TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles TreeView1.SelectedNodeChanged

    ' Some code

End Sub
```

You should run this in debug to find out what exactly is going on. I find a lot of times when events of this nature are run in asp.net, you have a conflicting event that "resets" the controls you are attempting to change.

Comment: the editor didn't bark but I still can not expand the tree view. I am adding an image to the post shortly.

Comment: @marc11h: I don't know that I can help you with why the tree view doesn't expand. I haven't looked at the source on the other page (and truly don't have the time to right now).

Comment: I understand, my time spent here is sometimes limited due to other tasks as well.

Comment: Got it, I was missing the Hanldes Me.Load from the end of the page load event and it was not firing. I have been walking through this for awhile now and kept missing this. Argh. Thanks @Joel your code worked great.